# Android Wear: Is it possible to use Wi-Fi direct with a smartwatch?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wifi, wifi-direct, sony-smartwatch

I'd like to create a connection between two or more smartwatches without their handheld devices.

I made this test to check the support

```
    FeatureInfo[] features = getPackageManager().getSystemAvailableFeatures();
    for (FeatureInfo info : features) {
        if (info != null && info.name != null && info.name.equalsIgnoreCase("android.hardware.wifi.direct")) {
            Log.i("wear main", "wifi direct supported");
            return;
        }
    }
    Log.i("wear main", "wifi direct not supported");
```

Since the following listener can tell if the service is available, I also made this test

```
    WifiP2pManager mManager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
    Channel mChannel = mManager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);

    mManager.discoverPeers(mChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Log.i("wear main", "wifi direct supported");
            return;

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int reasonCode) {
            Log.i("wear main", "wifi direct not supported");
            return;
        }
    });
```

I can only see that it's not supported (using sony smartwatch 3). Is it possible to use Wifi direct in android wear?

Comment: Did you ever get any further updates on this? I am investigating the feasibility of using Wifi direct or Nearby on a wearOS app but can't find a definitive answer on if it is supported.

Comment: No, I didn't. There is also the bluetooth adapted which is always supported.